# motion-mmalcam blue and black pictures

Tags: motion, raspberry-pi3

I have followed this [post](https://embeddedday.com/projects/raspberry-pi/a-step-further/install-motion-mmal/) on how to setup the motion-mmal for the raspberry pi 3. But when I tried to stream it what I only get are blue and black pixels. Blue when an object moves and black when stationary.
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLaSa.png)

Answer (score 2):

my research pays off.
The blue and black colors shows when you use "setup_mode on" on the conf file

[source](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MotionGuideBasicFeatures#output_motion)